# Content created by pseudo-elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I was wondering and playing with ::after yesterday and a question came to me:

Is it best to use pseudo-elements for redundant content, like a lorem-ipsum, or should I input it directly into my html.

Here's the example:

A font sheet displaying numerous sizes and font-families, using ::after to input the lorem-ipsum. While the file size is sure to be smaller this way, I was wondering if the processing of the CSS and information would be better this way or by plain html content.

Here's the code:

HTML

```
<h1>::after fonts showcase</h1>
<h2>Verdana</h2>
<p></p>
<p class="smaller"></p>

<h2 class="times">Times New Roman</h2>
<p class="times"></p>
<p class="times smaller"></p>

<h2 class="helvetica">Helvetica</h2>
<p class="helvetica"></p>
<p class="helvetica smaller"></p>

<h2 class="georgia">Georgia</h2>
<p class="georgia"></p>
<p class="georgia smaller"></p>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
::selection {
  color: tomato;
  background-color: white;
}

body {
  background-color: tomato;
  font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ad1a00, 2px 2px 1px #ad1a00;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 35px;
}
h2::after {
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
  height: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  content: "";
}

p {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
p::after {
  content: "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium     doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?";
}

.times {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", serif;
}

.helvetica {
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.georgia {
  font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.smaller {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

So yeah, it allows me to input the lorem-ipsum only once and to display it as much as I want with as many styles as I need, greatly reducing the final file size. But I was wondering about the true size of the rendering.

I don't know if my question is clear, but what do you guys think?

I understand that not every browser can use pseudo-elements like this, and that it is probably bad for accessibility, but given this is a font-styling showcase, blind people are not concerned.

And here's the visual of the example: http://codepen.io/rlacorne/pen/BdcvK

Thanks for your thoughts on the matter!

Answer (score 1):

That's an interesting question, and you've thought about the obvious objection - that it's putting a lot of content in the styling layer. As you suggest, this is a special case where accessibility might not be so important - although maybe blind people would still like to know what the page is doing, even if they can't tell the difference between the different fonts.

Having a lot of content outside the HTML might make the page slightly harder to maintain in future - any new developer would have to take a bit of time to discover your content declaration, whereas with HTML content it's in front of their noses. On the other hand, it is only one chunk of content you're using over and over again, which as you say makes for a smaller HTML file.

I'm not 100% sure about this, but my instinct is that browsers would parse straight HTML content more quickly - with the CSS rules they would have to modify their model of the DOM and apply the rule to each affected element before rendering. But I'm sure it's a very small difference in efficiency.

All in all, I'd say this'd be an acceptable use of a content declaration.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts on the question! I'll leave the question open so others can share theirs as well, but I'll up your answer, it's pretty interesting. :)